# configure apache tomcat 6 with mysql

Tags: mysql, tomcat, tomcat6

have changed web.xml and jsp to details for mysql and also put mysql drivers in classpath. yet unable to connect. mysql server of wamp running on port= 3306 and socket= /tmp/mysql.sock what necessary changes do i have to make in my application

Comment: @Gumbo: I think he means Apache Tomcat 6.

Comment: can you provide some more information, such as the error messages/exceptions/stack traces you're seeing and a description of any other symptoms?

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1387)

Answer (score 1):

Just put **mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar** in **`apache-tomcat-6.0.14\lib`** and restart the server.